# Pagination wrong display next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Custom pagination in JIRA ( http://d.pr/i/18cjv ) with 20 records limit size per page displays next page empty without records ( http://d.pr/i/19Dyh ), when there are 20 of 20 records.

This page should not occur, until it will be 21 record (also as for all next pages).

**JS:**

*var **page** - current page*

*var **total** - all records*

*var **records** - current records on page*

***renderTable(page)*** - shows records fields depend on page number

```
function renderPaging(parsedFieldsResult) {

    var firstResult = (page - 1) * 20;
            if (firstResult == 0) {
                firstResult = 1;
            }

    var lastResult = page * 20;
            if (lastResult > records) {
                lastResult = records;
            }

// summary with count of pages
            var pagingContent = '';
            pagingContent += '<div class="classname-pagination-summary">';
            pagingContent += '<strong class="first" id="table-first-page-bottom">';
            pagingContent += firstResult;
            pagingContent += '</strong>';
            pagingContent += ' &ndash; ';
            pagingContent += '<strong class="last" id="table-last-page-bottom">';
            pagingContent += lastResult;
            pagingContent += '</strong>';
            pagingContent += ' of ';
            pagingContent += '<strong class="total" id="table-pages-total-bottom">';
            pagingContent += records;
            pagingContent += '</strong>';
            pagingContent += '</div>';
            pagingContent += '<ol class="aui-nav aui-nav-pagination">';

// previous icon
            pagingContent += '<li class="aui-nav-previous">';
            pagingContent += '<a href="#" class="icon icon-previous" ';

            if (page > 1 && total > 1) {
                pagingContent += ' onclick="renderTable(';
                pagingContent += (page - 1);
                pagingContent += ')" ';
            }

            pagingContent += '>';
            pagingContent += '<span>Back</span>';
            pagingContent += '</a>';
            pagingContent += '</li>';


            var firstPage = page - 2;
            var lastPage = page + 2;

            if (firstPage < 1) {
                lastPage += (page - firstPage);
                firstPage = 1;
            }

            if (lastPage > total) {
                firstPage -= (lastPage - total);
                lastPage = total;
            }

            if (firstPage < 1) {
                firstPage = 1;
            }

// make current page selected (somewhere here mistake)
            for (var pageItem = firstPage; pageItem <= lastPage; pageItem++) {
                if (pageItem === page) {
                    pagingContent += '<li class="aui-nav-selected">';
                    pagingContent += pageItem;
                    pagingContent += '</li>';
                } else {
                    pagingContent += '<li><a class="page" href="#" ';
                    pagingContent += ' onclick="renderTable(';
                    pagingContent += pageItem;
                    pagingContent += ')" ';
                    pagingContent += ' >';
                    pagingContent += pageItem;
                    pagingContent += '</a></li>';
                }
            }
// next icon
            pagingContent += '<li class="aui-nav-next">';
            pagingContent += '<a href="#" class="icon icon-next" ';

            if (page < total && records > lastResult) {
                pagingContent += ' onclick="renderTable(';
                pagingContent += (page + 1);
                pagingContent += ')" ';
            }

            pagingContent += '>';
            pagingContent += '<span>Next</span>';
            pagingContent += '</a>';
            pagingContent += '</li>';
            pagingContent += '</ol>';

            jQuery("#pagination-id").html(pagingContent);           
  }
```

(It's not my own code, i think it is badly constructed)

What condition should be added?

I'll be glad of any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please add fiddle or plunker.

Comment: Hello, 
can't load content fields from rest link to fiddle